# User profile info null in Firebase Auth with Google Sign-In

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

How can I get the name and profile photo of a Google account from a FirebaseUser?

I'm following Firebase's Android [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) on integrating Google Sign-In and Firebase Authentication. When I authenticate with Google Sign-In, I can get user profile information from `GoogleSignInAccount#getPhotUrl()` and `GoogleSignInAccount#getDisplayName()`.

I can sign in to Firebase with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(account)` (where `account` is the same authenticated `GoogleSignInAccount` object. But I get null values for the user profile information from the Firebase side.

Google Sign-In result callback:

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
    account.getEmail(); // Valid email
    account.getDisplayName(); // Valid name
    account.getPhotoUrl(); // Valid Uri
    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
}
```

Google Sign-In + Firebase Auth:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        user.getEmail(); // Valid email
                        user.getDisplayName(); // null
                        user.getPhotoUrl(); // null
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to get those values from the `FirebaseUser` object in stead of `GoogleSignInAccount`?

Comment: @AlexMamo A library like [FirebaseUI for Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) doesn't expose the Google Sign-In classes and a FirebaseUser is the way to get the profile information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by using a new Firebase project and new Gmail account.